# Why doesn't the cache-control value update in Elixir/Phoenix 1.2?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a JSON api setup via Phoenix 1.2....

In router.ex, I pipe my JSON endpoints thru pipeline as follows:

```
pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end
```

Whne I try and add a cache-control value to the response headers in the JSON response I send back to my browser making the request to the GET endpoint via:

```
  conn
  |> put_resp_header("cache-control", "max-age=2000")
```

I don't see that the cache-control has been updated...

```
req_headers: [{"host", "localhost:4000"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"},               
  {"cache-control", "max-age=0"}, {"upgrade-insecure-requests", "1"},  
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up things. If you want to have it as a response header, check the `resp_headers`, not `req_headers`. Otherwise - you should use [Plug.Conn.put_req_header/3](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_req_header/3) and not `put_resp_header`.